# SSTab and each tab's child controls

Tags: vb6

The SSTab does hide/show the child controls by shifting them to/from a negative value. Basically all child controls do have the SSTab control instance as parent HWND.

Is there any way to determine the tab index for the child controls - any other than looping the SSTab.Tab property? How does the SSTab instance manage the child controls to tab association?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  What, exactly, is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I've seen. Your best bet is too move each tab's controls into a dedicated picturebox or frame.
This allows you to tell what the control's parent is and eventually move away from the buggy SSTab control.

There is an article I wrote explaining this and various other flaws with the SSTab control at:
http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Tabbed_dialogs

Comment: see my answer for an easy way to overcome the tabbing issues

Answer (score 1):

The sstab control shifts controls that are not on the active tab by -75000. If you only want to know what controls are on the active tab vs all the other controls on the inactive tabs you can inspect the left property and the container property.

The following code will toggle the visibility on the controls when the user clicks the tabs so the tab order is preserved

```
Private Sub SSTab1_Click(PreviousTab As Integer)

    Dim o As Object

    For Each o In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf o.Container Is SSTab Then
            If o.Left < -40000 Then
                'control is not on the current tab
                o.Visible = False
            Else
                'control is on the current tab
                o.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If you need to know which controls are on specific tabs, you could call the click event via code and build a list of controls that have lefts > 0